# How can I model the impacts of improved agriculture technologies and food aid in a multimarket model?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, development-economics, development

Given a multimarket model for staple agricultural commodities wheat, rice, maize and sorghum, in a low-income economy, Im trying to figure out how I can use the multimarket framework to look at the impacts of bringing in food aid to the economy as well as introducing improved agricultural technologies. Would it just be re-defining the equations used to solve the model to incorporate the changes and then re-solve the model to determine the results?

This village economy has 4 households including poor rural, rich rural, poor urban, and rich-urban. Would all or any of these households be harmed by these two changes? I think that the food aid would benefit the poor households and the improved ag tech could potentially harm the rural poor since they would make up most of the ag labor force which might be harmed by introducing new ag technology.

Comment: Hi! It would be great if you could tell us what you have tried (in terms of modelling) so far.

Comment: I haven't tried anything specifically. I'm just trying to get some intuition on how to introduce shocks to the economy and how I can see the impacts of those shocks.